# Getting frames @30 fps with Logitech C270 and Raspi 3 model B using libuvc

Tags: pi-3, usb, webcam, v4l2

I'm designing a solution that requires to capture **3 frames in 100ms** and send it to the Raspi-3 model B. It's okay for me to receive uncompressed frames because I'm going to **capture only 5 frames** and pause the streaming for a while until some other event occurs.

Unfortunately I'm not able to capture the frames at this rate (30 fps) using **libuvc** library. There is an **example code** that says it captures **YUYV frames at 30 fps**, but apparently **It doesn't**.

https://int80k.com/libuvc/doc/

above is the link to the example code that claims it captures frames @30 fps.

I have also tried the 'avconv' tool to capture video/frames on my Pi. It captures @22-26 fps on average. so why can't I obtain it by this code?

Comment: Where does it say that it captures 30fps? Does it do that on a Pi? If so which model Pi? Please edit your question and add the answers to these questions as well as the code you are using.

Comment: It's pi-3 model B.  No it doesn't say it captures at 20 fps. But surely It doesn't capture at 30 fps using libuvc example code. I used clock() to measure the time in callback thread and it says it takes around "a Second" to capture and receive 5 frames.

Comment: The answers to my questions belong in your question not the comments. You claim that the code (which you have not included) will capture at 30fps. But you have not told us where it says that, nor if that claim applies to a Pi, a laptop or desktop? I know what your Pi is based on the tags, my question is what model Pi was the sample code run on to make the claim of 30fps?

Comment: https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc/blob/master/src/example.c
here is the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: FOR THE THIRD TIME THESE ANSWERS/DETAILS BELONG IN YOUR QUESTION NOT THE COMMENTS!

Comment: I see nowhere in that repo that makes the claim that the code can capture @ 30fps.

Comment: Have added the another link in the question that claims so. please have a look on this.

Comment: It makes the claim of 30fps, at  640x480. is that in fact the resolution you are using? The bigger issue is that you are likely comparing apples and oranges. Nowhere that I can see does it say it will do that on a Pi with 1GB of memory. The Pi may be powerful for its size but it is unrealistic to expect the same performance as that of a modern laptop or desktop computer, with several times the memory, CPU.

Comment: How does 5 frames vs 30 or 100 frames make a difference. Any computer can only do so much work per unit of time.

Comment: You're right. I'm aware of the resolution and the capacity of Pi.
Do you mean It cannot even handle mere 5 Frames on 1 GB RAM and 1.2 GHz or so?

Comment: Not with the current code according to your measurements.

Comment: Can you please explain why and is there any other option to achieve that?

Comment: If you only need 5 frames... then why not just capture the 5 frames? I know you said it must be 3 frames per 100ms.. but why? You can get 5 frames in 125ms at the 25fps .. I suppose 30FPS will only work on lower resolution too.. did you try that??

Comment: That link is for the driver... can your camera actually support 30fps??!?!

Comment: My camera does support 30fps. Yes, I am capturing just 5 frames but it takes 800ms which is not suitable for my application. If I could even get 25fps that would be way better than current case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
**It does give frames @30 fps!**
But to confirm that, I went into the library file of libuvc i.e. **stream.c** and found out that the moment the frame is populated into the buffer, we can provide a time stamp into the structure in which the buffer is filled.(*capture_time*).
Call gettimeofday(&*strmh->capture_time*, NULL) in *populate_frame*() and try printing the same.
The difference between successive capture_time shows the time taken for each frame to be captured.